# PySpark - Calculate Jaccard similarity from a single column dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe similar to following:

```
--------------------+
|           values|
+--------------------+
|162440,10204,1622288|
|199,429,150, 2323989|
|             162440 |
|            87878787|
|       12345,5678901|
|                2811|
|  15149892,1642,2811|
|221444,221444,729889|
|           1499,1499|
```

I want to calculate jaccard similarity scores of all values with each other based on co-occurrence and count of individual occurrence

I tried creating a co-occurrence matrix and getting jaccard similarity from that but running into performance issues since the size of the matrix is huge

Can someone help in getting Jaccard similarity from this in an optimized manner using PySpark udf?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed description with example solutions? Possibly your code as well in simplified form so that we can optimize it.